# How to build a package from source on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS and ROS Kinetic?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two packages that I could build from source for their respective reasons. The first one is `ardrone-autonomy`. This package, as indicated by [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/252390/cant-install-ardrone_autonomy/) question, is not being installed on my computer with the command `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy`. The other package is `lsd-slam`. This package, as indicated by [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/250822/how-to-install-lsd_slam-on-my-ros/) question, must be built from source. `lsd-slam` is yet to be released for **ros-kinetic**.

Now The standard instructions for building from source are:

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ rosinstall_generator ros_desktop <package_name> --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
$ wstool merge -t src kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
$ wstool update -t src
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r --os=debian:jessie
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

But when you install kinetic using the command, `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`, the folder `~/ros_catkin_ws` is not created in your root directory. So how exactly am I supposed to proceed with the installation of `ardrone-autonomy`? I know [these](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) are the instructions for installing `lsd-slam`, but this also need me to use `catkin_make` and that would need `~/ros_catkin_ws`. What exactly am I supposed to do here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-16.04-lts-and-ros-kinetic?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-20**:
Those are definitely **not** the "standard instructions for building from source", if only for the fact that you are forcing `rosdep` to consider dependency mapping for *Debian Jessie*. Also: this will build *all* of ROS, which is completely unnecessary (as I mentioned in #q252390).

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-20**:
So how would I go about building from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer to #q208963, but to make it slightly more generic (so this is an example set of commands for a 'regular' ROS package, not one with special requirements and / or system dependencies that have to be built from sources):

```
# make sure you have sourced the correct setup.bash file for your ROS distribution already

# go to workspace src space
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src

# acquire a copy of the sources of the package that you want to build.
# For a package hosted on github, you'd do something like (where
# $organisation and $package obviously depend on what it is that you
# want to build):
git clone https://github.com/$organisation/$package.git

# change to the workspace base directory (this has to be the working directory
# in a minute anyway when building, and we can shorten the 'rosdep' command a bit)
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws

# we need to make sure you have all dependencies installed.

# once in a while, update our local database
rosdep update

# then check (and install) for any missing dependencies
# NOTE: we ask rosdep to check for ROS Indigo here, if you are using another ROS
# distribution, substitute that there (ie: for Kinetic, use 'kinetic', without the quotes)
rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo

# now build
catkin_make
```

If compilation was successful, you should now have a `build` and `devel` directory next to the `src` directory, and after sourcing `/path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` you should now be able to use the package you just built from sources.

Note: just cloning a package from somewhere is *not* enough. Packages most likely depend on other packages and / or system libraries to be present, and we use `rosdep` to install those for us. We do depend on the author(s) of the package that you are building to have properly declared their dependencies. If they haven't done so, `catkin_make` will tell you about that (in the form of "Can't find .." etc errors).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-23**:
I have posted a new question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/252786/trying-to-build-ardrone_autonomy-from-source-on-my-ubuntu-mate-and-failing/) related to this topic.